# Simple Server Load Testing Response Times

Tags: go, concurrency, load-testing, goroutine

I would like to create an application using Golang to load test a server app I have running. There are some preceeding activities to sending the request or else I would use something like ab etc. I am calling something similar to the below in X number of goroutines.

```
func sendRequest() *time.Duration {

    xmlBody := "SomeXmlHere"
    start := time.Now()
    resp, err := http.Post("www.example.com", "text/xml", strings.NewReader(xmlBody))
    requestTime := time.Since(start)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    response, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    return &requestTime
}
```

When the request is initiated, the runtime will switch to another goroutine while the request is ongoing. So my question is, will the response times be skewed if another goroutine is long running and blocks the call to `time.Since()`? Is there a way around this problem to obtain accurate response times?

Comment: First: Check `err` first before defering `Body.Close()` and `ReadAll`. For your question: I have no idea what you are asking. Yes, of course the runtime runs all goroutines concurrently and "will switch" between them and this switch takes time. So a switch from goroutine 1 during Post and back before doing `time.Since(start)` will be recorded as a "longer" response duration. But: The Post request will be orders of magnitude slower than this goroutine switching so why care? Are you afraid that you run out of threads to service all goroutines in a timely maner?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will make sure to check the error. I have found when I ramp up to say 100 concurrent connections that the response times increase quite dramatically. I'm wondering how much of that time is spent by the app doing other activities, and how much of it is actually the response time. 

I'm not necessarily concerned by the switching, but whether the time is spent while the application is sending out other requests or running other goroutines.

Comment: Improved the question towards the end, does that make more sense?

Comment: The response isn't done until you read the response body. You're only timing the response headers here. Goroutines are run concurrently, a slow response will not block another request.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that @JimB. I'm not suggesting the responses will block, but that other goroutines that are beginning new requests may block the reading the response?

Comment: Nothing will "block" the call to time.Since(). Once the Post request is done time.Since() will be called totally unblocked. Go doesn't do magical "blocking" (some explicit constructs like channel operations block). Given you load testing machine has enough CPU the time.Since() will happen "right after" the Post request. Note that if you overload your request generator this _will_ lead to delays, but this is not "blocking", its just "your CPU has more work to do than it can do in parallel".

Comment: Apologies for the delay in coming back to this. @Volker How might the overloading of the CPU that you suggest be detected, if we are uncertain how long a request is expected to take?

Comment: Read about load testing and performance tuning of Go applications, then measure. Comments in a SO question are an inappropriate medium to discuss such things.